# Angular 6 How to define a custom debug function in Angular Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-pipe, angular-observable

Just got a question in creating a custom debug

I've followed a tutorial for making a custom debug, below are code

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/index';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

declare module 'rxjs/internal/Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    debug: (...any) => Observable<T>;
  }
}

Observable.prototype.debug = (message: string) => {
  return this.do(
    (next) => {
      if (!environment.production) {
        console.log(message, next);
      }
    },
    (err) => {
      if (!environment.production) {
        console.error('ERROR >>', message, err);
      }
    },
    () => {
      if (!environment.production) {
        console.log('Completed - ');
      }
    }
  );
};
```

When I am using the debug in a service, it gave me this error

> this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(...).debug is not a function
>       at QuoteService.push../src/app/services/quote.service.ts.QuoteService.getQuote (quote.service.ts:19)

```js
export class QuoteService {

  constructor(@Inject('BASE_CONFIG') private config,
              private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getQuote(): Observable<Quote> {
    const uri = `${this.config.uri}/quotes/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}`;
    return this.httpClient.get(uri)
      .pipe(map((res: Quote) => res as Quote))
      .debug('quote: ');
  }
}
```

when I wrap the debug in a pipe(), it simply just say

> ERROR ReferenceError: debug is not defined

I have no clue how to solve this, is any one have an idea?

Thanks for any comments

Comment: That's not a pipeable operator you have defined, it's just a method on Observable proto.

Comment: thanks for the commenting! I've figured out by defining a pipe inspired by your comments

Answer (score 0):

the approach to make a debug above comes from Angular 4 which in Angular 6 I've come up with a more clear and easy way

look at the code:

```js
import {pipe} from 'rxjs/index';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/internal/operators';

export const debug = (message: string) => pipe(
  tap(
    (next) => {
      if (!environment.production) {
        console.log(message, next);
      }
    },
    (err) => {
      if (!environment.production) {
        console.error('ERROR >>', message, err);
      }
    },
    () => {
      if (!environment.production) {
        console.log('Completed - ');
      }
    }
  )
);
```

and then can be used anywhere needed by chaining in pipe operator

```js
getQuote(): Observable<Quote> {
    const uri = `${this.config.uri}/quotes/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}`;
    return this.httpClient.get(uri)
      .pipe(debug('quote: '), map((res: Quote) => res as Quote));
  }
```

As simple as it is